# Algebraic Grid Generation

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-science

I am new to topic " Algebraic Grid Generation". I want to find a simple example where we solve the host equation, let us say the heat equation, numerically in the computational domain then transform it back to the physical domain. All the references I found discuss the general steps without providing a single practical example

Comment: Did you look up finite differences and heat equation?

Comment: Actually I have been working on numerical methods (FDM) for solving the heat equation for more than 3 years. @JohnAlexiou

Comment: maybe then *https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/* is a better fit.